# Cannot change password for user postgres in postgresql

Tags: password, postgresql

I have made the following entry in pg_hba.conf

> local   all all trust

but still

> su postgres

does not accept blank as password. I am not able to run psql nor pg_ctl for same reason as most of the files are owned by postgres.

> EDIT1

```
dhaval@ubuntu:~$ su -c "pg_ctl reload -D template1"
Password: 
su: Authentication failure

dhaval@ubuntu:~$ su -c psql
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
```

I am giving the root password above but I guess its expecting "postgres" superuser password. I dont have the same. I need to reset it.

> EDIt2

```
dhaval@ubuntu:~$ sudo -i -u postgres
[sudo] password for dhaval:
postgres@ubuntu:~$ psql
Welcome to psql 8.3.7, the PostgreSQL interactive terminal.
```

The above has taken me postgreSQL command prompt. But I am still not sure why the "trust" was not working.

Comment: "trust" is working fine -- **Postgres** trusts you, the **OS** does not (you are not root, therefore when you try to `su` to postgres you must enter the **postgres OS user**'s password)  -- There are two different authentication stores, and two separate "users" here (one set for the OS and one for DB).  Also note that you don't need to `su` to postgres (see the `-U` option to psql to specify a database username other than the currently-logged-in OS user)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Operating System* User passwords (the thing you're asked for when you try to su) are not the same as *Postgres* User Passwords (the thing you don't need when you set auth to `trust` in `pg_hba.conf`).

You need to set a valid **OS** password for the **Operating System**'s postgres user and enter that password in order to su to that user (Or su to that user from  root, where you won't be asked for a password).

Typically the postgres **OS** user password is locked out after DB initialization since the only thing that needs to run as postgres is `pg_ctl`, which can be launched with `su -c` from your init scripts (that run as root and therefore don't need the password).

Comment: Yes, but to enter postgresql I need the postgres superuser password which I dont have.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are trying to do 'su postgres'. Ubuntu does not allow a non-root user to switch to another user. So you may need to assume root and then su postgres.

To become 'root', try:

sudo su -

After that, try:

su postgres

That should get you access as the 'postgres' user as understood by the OS.

Hope this helps.

best
Vishal Belsare